# Tests are not being executed for TestNG

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, testng

trying to run all my Cucumber tests with TestNG. However my suite is not being found.

I saw some stackoverflow questions about it but none of them solved my problem.

Runner - junitRunner.java

```
package testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "src/test/resources/features/",
glue = "br.mysteps.steps"
)

public class junitRunner {

}
```

testng.xml

```
<suite name="SeleniumSuite">
<test name="testAll">
       <classes>
          <class name="testRunner.junitRunner"/>
       </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>       
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run the testng.xml file as TestNG, the tests are not found as below

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.11.0
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE 
suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your 
file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.

===============================================
SeleniumSuite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to basically use TestNG to run your cucumber tests, then you would need to extend `cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests`.

For more detailed samples on how to use TestNG to run your cucumber tests, please refer to the examples [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-calculator-testng).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I've tried to however the class AbstractTestNGCucumberTests() is not being found to extend.

Comment: Please refer to the link that I shared. It has all the information including the maven dependencies you need to add.

Comment: I've fixed my dependencies, it was a bit different. However now I am facing java.lang.NullPointerException .. and really no idea what is the problem.. :(

Comment: so, as you helped me to solve the original problem, going to finish this ask. Thank you!